# How to call the "when" macro in a Chicken Scheme macro?

Tags: macros, scheme, chicken-scheme

Chicken Scheme defines a `(when)` macro, equivalent to `(if (begin))`. However, when I try to call this from one of my own macros, it complains that the "variable" is not defined:

```
(define-syntax blah
 (ir-macro-transformer
  (lambda (expr inject compare)
   (when something
    (do-something)))))
```

> Error: during expansion of (blah ...) - unbound variable: when

What can I `import` to make this work?

Comment: If `something` is false, what would be the expansion?

Comment: There wouldn't be one. It's equivalent to `(if something (begin (do-something)))`, which is perfectly valid code.

Comment: Yes, but remember that the result is evaluated as code. The result of `(if something (begin (do-something)))` when `something` is false would not be a proper code and a macro needs to become code. Your program will stop with the cryptic error *illegal non-atomic object: #<unspecified>* since the false value returned is the value `#<unspecified>`

Comment: I realise this. And this happens a lot when I write macros, as I've just started with Scheme. But that's not the point, and has nothing to do with the error I'm getting. All I want to do is be able to call built-in Chicken Scheme macros such as `when`. This is entirely unrelated to whether or not my macro is "correct".

Comment: Ok. That aside you need to import symbols for use in macro expansion time. For eggs it is `(use-for-syntax <name-of-egg>)`. I guess we need to wait for a more advanced chicken user to answer what to import.

Comment: Yeah, I know about `use-for-syntax`. I was kinda hoping for the _what_ ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same answer as [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884486/how-to-call-existing-macros-e-g-let-values-from-a-macro-in-chicken-scheme/38889273); just `(import-for-syntax chicken)` and you're all set.