# How to use existing macros - e.g. `let-values` - from a macro expander procedure in Chicken Scheme?

Tags: macros, scheme, chicken-scheme

How do I call built-in Chicken Scheme macros - specifically `let-values` in this instance - from my own macros?

```
(define-syntax ...
 (ir-macro-transformer
  (lambda (expr inject compare)
   (let-values (...) ...
    ...
```

> unbound variable: let-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a bug I'm afraid.  A simple `(import-for-syntax chicken)` did the trick for me.

In CHICKEN 5, this works without such a strange import.

Comment: Is there a way to see what symbols are imported in syntax phase in Chicken 4.9?

Comment: @Sylwester: There's a hack: `(map car (##sys#macro-environment))` shows you internal info about what's available for expanding to (I think...?).  With `(map car (##sys#meta-macro-environment))` you can see the procedures available to procedural macros.

Comment: @sjamaan So the first one lists available macros, and the second lists available functions? But the output of both calls seem to be names of macros....?

Comment: @sjamaan ...and what is Chicken 5? I see no mention on the website of any version - even beta - after 4.11.

Comment: @SodAlmighty: It's currently in development.  See [our roadmap](http://wiki.call-cc.org/chicken-5-roadmap) and the [issue tracker](http://bugs.call-cc.org/query?group=status&milestone=5.0) for progress.